# how to distribute raw value into multiple blank raw in the same column in data frame using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, consumption

my data as:

```
id   date      consumption
1    1/2/2020   500
1    1/3/2020   nan
1    1/4/2020   nan
1    1/5/2020   nan
1    1/6/2020   900
```

consumption column represents a monthly reading of consumption and is cumulative.
i need to distribute consumption 900 on nan cell in (consumption) column and depend on scale factors i had
the data i need to be as example like:

```
id   date    value
1    1/2/2020   500
1    1/3/2020   650
1    1/4/2020   700
1    1/5/2020   800
1    1/6/2020   900
```

Comment: I do not quite understand which rule you are using to fill you nan values..? Why do you add 150 from 1.2.20 and only 50 from 1.3.20 to 1.4.20?

Comment: What have you already tried? e.g by using `fillna` or `interpolate`?

Comment: i want to fill nan with values between tow values(500 - 900) for each month and the values to be fill must be above 500 extracted from equation like (500+(daily consumption* factor* 30)

Comment: this is just example.. my data set is to big and have many nan between tow raw values for unique id

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: my data set is big, so i need to make loop on consumption column for the same id , and if i find nan between tow values as in example case, i want to fill nan field in between these tow values with a value  must be above first value and less second value

Answer (score 0):

let's start first by the code for recreating the example data  to test on it :

```
import pandas as pd
data={"id":[1,2,3,4,5],"date":["1/2/2020","1/3/2020","1/4/2020","1/5/2020","1/6/2020"],"consumption":[500,None,None,None,900]}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

which give us our initial datframe

[image: dfinitial]

Next we're going create a list filler, that calculates the values that should be in between ; for our example :

```
  dfnotnull=df[df.iloc[:,2].notnull()]
  amount=dfnotnull.iloc[-1,2]-dfnotnull.iloc[0,2]
  count=dfnotnull.iloc[i+1,0]-dfnotnull.iloc[i,0]-1

  filler=[dfnotnull.iloc[0,2]]
  for j in range(count):
    filler.append(filler[j]+amount/(count+1))
  filler.append(dfnotnull.iloc[-1,2])
  filler

  df['consumption'] = filler
  df
```

which give us this result :

[image: example result]

To get more generic result , we would be looping through the notnull values dataframe , between each two non null values we fill the values as we saw in the example:

```
dfnotnull=df[df.iloc[:,2].notnull()]
for i in range(len(dfnotnull)-1):
  amount=dfnotnull.iloc[i+1,2]-dfnotnull.iloc[i,2]
  count=len(df.loc[df.consumption.isnull(), 'consumption'])
  filler=[dfnotnull.iloc[i,2]]
  for j in range(count):
    filler.append(filler[j]+amount/(count+1))
  filler.append(dfnotnull.iloc[i+1,2])
  filler
  df.loc[df.loc[df.iloc[:,2].notnull()].index[i]:df.loc[df.iloc[:,2].notnull()].index[i+1],"consumption"]=filler
```

Comment: thanks for answering, please if i want  fill the values and get each one depend on equation like (first notnull value+(consumption in day* factor* 30))

Comment: you can change it in the filler list to be assigned to ;